# PowerMock.whenNew() returns NULL if running with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, powermock

I have mocked 2 classes with mockStatic() and use whenNew on this classes. Everything works perfectly when running in IDE, but fails with `./gradlew test`. Mocked constructor returns null instead of mock object.
Are there any issues in running powerMock with Gradle?

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: It's just NullPointerException. Constructor returns null instead of mock

Comment: There is no known issue with PowerMock and Gradle. Could you provide example? By the way,  `mockStatic()` is required to mock static methods and not new call. `whenNew()` requires that class which call constructor is added to `@PrepareForTest`. I'm a bit confused that `mockStatic` and `whenNew` is used for the same classes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Please provide a real piece of code; not just explanations what your code is doing.